# cloud-to-cloud > actions console > account linking でエラーが発生する

Tags: oauth

「Google Actions」を新規作成しました、「Account linking」が下図のように設定しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ブラウザで動作確認する場合、問題がありませんが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アプリ「Google Home」で「デバイスの追加」を行う場合、「code」が正しく返しましたが、下図のようなエラーが発生されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

戻りコードURI

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/smarthome-63b16?code=RngBAiEMlJjVuaYpwCevLWT1Om_FAJ9GvPMz39aOtapHCbD9iJ4sUSgKKtr-oUB6wYLJLtVWuEuHhmIx4I0iB9E8MLhy7TzQ6R9oXMr5sMZzr3J5U4szSKIh74q1cBVk&state=AGsGMl27ZkmHPAYA8hRyGIEXLwYpsAbf21ZDa8YAz0fhjzwdC-aMB5eplvO1W8uNNX85b94z46VSJEpYFOWW2S-kEXpFUODnKxe7rUQGQGOqVwVoJZnkTtsgFpQHN6aXWm63i1FF3orAZ7ow3FGWpzj3ZxABrwfxXeb8wSTA94b3tcHGa_pv-PUvNDP20JcK5mmc9q6NpTK5Z17qfsieClsI_jbbhFdpZ8fp9IeJ2j5Flp1Mfy9ScIKRgZkhZwBxZy_SNdmsNejMzWPsPC7PQn_-zarzOWt68dQ9dy4q2HPSDl-S6V-2d1UV6dnWZKULycNSNPPlxg9LNyS9u4EqS-cyAWFEtzn9gWLxXnJUMJC8OldQRhjWOrRaNfM7n3ie2W9yhxdPbO6AcAxaJVXoj7ddIFhdx03QMlyIytdlvpQCxuB_WEbhIv5ZhDsD_5vvHxZ6ptVcXEIX7bbN5u_KOpa8RzwGPsqN1zQtpXUq4P6sF6Loy0Db3_nlSgWTJWn_5-0ukb--0X1QoaZjQtA6nX4C6G0ESB2XQHQrOGU4DDgxGyhZ6Er3pPbyyLtUeYI-GhKtOFXXxFz47-0TzTdTgHcZyXE39JaLNQ80WKUFcinrk1IJ7dqYqwcyhrwEKT6XXtUxj82NUJs0oNuXtziFyg9onINL-tzkLzLqw5UapknMSLtPI_ETXlM
```

Authサーバにトークン交換リクエストがありません。

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the authorize server is not successfully redirecting to "https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/smarthome-63b16?code=~" with status code 301.

This is because a token exchange request would be sent to the Auth server if the redirect had been successful.

Please check the response from the authorize server.